# google app engine java backend _ah/start

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I read in the google app engine backend documentation for java and it's said that we need to give the url for the backend to be _ah/start. Is the java backend url-pattern in web.xml needs to be _ah/start? Can I change that into my custom url name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the App Engine documentation:

```
A backend instance can be targeted with HTTP requests to
http://[instance]-dot-[backend_name]-dot-[your_app_id].appspot.com,
or at your application's custom domain.
```

So you can use whatever domain is configured for your app. `_ah/start` is a way to start the backend, i.e. a simple request sent to:

```
backend1-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/start
```

will start the backend. You don't have to do it - you can send any request to a backend, and the App Engine will start it for you if no instances are running.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for your answer. So in the web.xml I can define it like following : 
<pre> <code>
<servlet-name>eventUpdate</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/backendupdate</url-pattern>  
<security-constraint> 

<web-resource-collection> 
<web-resource-name>mybackend</web-resource-name> 
<url-pattern>/backendupdate</url-pattern> 
</web-resource-collection> 
<auth-constraint> 
<role-name>*</role-name> 
</auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
</code> </pre> and in the cron.xml : <url>/backendupdate</url> <schedule>every 10 minutes</schedule> <target>backendname</target> is that correct? thanks